# osm2pgsql with PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL 9.0. I've installed osm2pgsql package from Debian repositories and now I have two versions of postgres databse installed on my machine (9.0 and 9.1 - installed with osm2pgsql). How can I configure osm2pgsql and postgis to work with 9.0 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian usually installs multiple versions of PostgreSQL on sequential ports beginning at 5432, so your first installation is at 5432, your second at 5433, and so forth.

PostGIS is typically installed into the database though the mechanism of doing this is different in 9.0 and 9.1 (in 9.0, review the docs to find the appropriate installation method, and you may need to install from source.  You would then run a specific .sql file to import the relevant functions.  9.1 uses the `CREATE EXTENSION` syntax.

For client programs you can set which PostgreSQL installation it will connect to by default (i.e. unless the program specifies otherwise) by setting the `PGPORT` to the appropriate setting.